# saving and loading string inside an arraylist and running method which prints the arraylist

Tags: java

ive been trying to solve this problem for the last 5 days. Ok I have 4 methods, add which allows me to add hotels to a selected place. view which allows me to look at the list of hotels ive added to certain places. I also have a save method and a load method which i am trying to get to fun

```
import java.io.*;

public class ArrayLists   
{   bjectInputStream(inFileStream);


    in.readObject();
    in.close();


      } 
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
{
    System.out.println("Error");
} 
catch (IOException ex) 
{
    System.out.println("Error");
} 
catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
{
    System.out.println("Error");
}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are discarding the object you are reading from your file:

```
in.readObject();
```

You should probably change it to:

```
nyArray = (ArrayList<String>) in.readObject();
```

Also, since the contents of the file where you persist your `ArrayList` are not textual, I'd suggest you change the name of the file to something else, for example `hello.dat` instead of `hello.txt`.

Comment: Ive replaced the in.readObject() to nyArray = in.readArrayList<String>

Comment: I now get void types are not allowed here

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? (there was a cast missing)

Comment: You are a god, 5 days of my time to your 5 minutes. God bless